# Using partial within map

Tags: r, purrr

I've came up to an interesting problem. I have a function of three variables, let's say (for simplicity and transparency) it is this:

```
my_fun <- function(a, b, c) paste(a, b, c, sep = '-')
```

I want to create multiple functions with only argument `c` for several combinations of `a` anb `b`. I am using functions `map2` and `partial` (both from package `purrr`).

```
require(purrr)
funs <- map2(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5], partial, ...f = my_fun)
```

I would expect each function in the list of functions produce different output, but that is not true.

```
funs[[1]]('hi')    # [1] "e-E-hi"
funs[[3]]('hi')    # [1] "e-E-hi"
funs[[5]]('hi')    # [1] "e-E-hi"
```

I am able to create different solution to my problem, so my question isn't "how to do it". I am rather interested in why it does this.

---

Another example using base `mapply`:

```
mapply(partial, letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5], MoreArgs = list(...f = my_fun))[[1]]('hi')
# [1] "e-E-hi"
```

Comment: its a lazy evaluation thing... adding `.lazy=FALSE` solves it, but why isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that `partial` uses lazy evaluation, which within `map2` means that it is storing `.x` and `.y` instead of `a` and `A`. Luckily there is a function argument for that, and we can use:

```
funs <- map2(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5], partial, ...f = my_fun, .lazy = FALSE)

funs[[1]]('hi')
# [1] "a-A-hi"
```

If you look at your version, we see this:

```
funs[[1]]

# function (...) 
# my_fun(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...)
# <environment: 0x00000000201d9598>
```

And the same for each one of the other 4.

Now, if we look into that environment, we can see:

```
ls(envir = environment(funs[[1]]))
# [1] "i"
```

So there is an object stored `i` in there, that will determine which `.x` and `.y` we get and its value is:

```
get('i', environment(funs[[1]]))
# [1] 5
```

Also note that your arguments are stored there as well, but are hidden due to their starting with a `.`:

```
ls(envir =     environment(funs[[1]]), all.names = TRUE)
# [1] "..." ".f"  ".x"  ".y"  "i" 
get('.x', envir = environment(funs[[1]]))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

So for all of these, we get the same result. Specifically, the executed call ends up being:

```
my_fun(letters[1:5][[5]], LETTERS[1:5][[5]], 'hi')
```

The lazy evaluation is not playing nice here, and using the stored internal loop counter inside `map2`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize the arguments in `map` are with dot (therefore hidden). I saw nothing but the variable `i` in the environments of individual functions.

Comment: Indeed, I have added some clarification to that point to the answer.